# Playframework suggested import statements not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hello I am using eclipse and I have been trying to learn the play framework 2.0, but one thing is slowing me down.

Eclipse can not give me any suggested import statements for all play framework related methods. So, I have to manually copy-paste the import statements from tutorials (which it then builds fine, and removes the red lines).

I have tried all combinations of `eclipsify` and `eclipsify with source=true;` and refresh automatically. (I also have tried with Scala IDE installed and uninstalled but don't think this has anything to do with this issue)

So I am beginning to think play framework doesn't support this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Quick Fix](http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/features/typingviewing.html#quick-fix-imports) on the missing type? (CMD+1 on OSX)

Also, did you know about the [Setup and use Play framework 2.0 in Scala IDE 2.0](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play20scalaide20/index.html) tutorial?

If you can't get it to work, just drop by the [scala-ide-user ML](https://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user) and I'm sure we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It does, I started recently a project with Scala and play 2.0 to probe it. I had problems with the directory of the project which i wanted to make the eclipsify. Before the eclipsify i think you have to make a play run. It needs to be compilated to add eclipse conf files.

Hope it helps.